# Why doesn't my buck converter work properly?

Tags: pwm, buck, mosfet-driver, arduino-uno

Such is my circuit:

[image: Circuit]

Vin is a constant DC source. This circuit will take a random DC input between 12.6V and 48V, and then maintain a constant output voltage of 5V.

At the left bottom corner, there is a voltage divider circuit, where we measure our input voltage. I use the following code for measurement:

```
int A0in = analogRead(A0); 
float Vin = 11 * (A0in + 0.5) * 5 / 1023;
```

And it is working. Since this is just a prototype, I selected Vin = 48V. Arduino prints 48.09V onto the LCD.

The fifth pin will be our PWM pin, I set it to 7812.5 Hz by the following command:

TCCR0B = TCCR0B & B11111000 | B00000010;

(I will use 62.5kHz when I finish.)

Arduino will measure the voltage and then calculate the duty cycle to generate the required PWM.

So we have a PMOS switch and we drive its gate with the circuit upside. (I think there is some problem with it?)

After the switch, comes our buck converter circuit and 5 Ω load.

The issue is when I simulate the circuit, the voltage on the load is not 5 Volts, it is 28 Volts. Why my circuit doesn't work?

Here is my full code:

```
void setup()
{ 
  TCCR0B = TCCR0B & B11111000 | B00000010; 
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  float Vin = 11 * (A0in + 0.5) * 5 / 1023; 
  float D = 255 * 5 / Vin;
  analogWrite(5, D); 
}
```

Edit:

[image: Oscilloscope]

^^^
Channel B is the PWM output.
Channel A is the cathode of the diode.

[image: Vgs]

Vgs is, on the other hand, gives values varying between -40V and 22.8V

Comment: Your circuit would burn (if you built it) when the supply voltage exceeds much above circa 20 volts because the MOSFET gate-source voltage would exceed its maximum value. Try lowering your duty cycle but, don't use supply voltages greater than 20 volts until you fix the driver problem.

Comment: Can you share the schematic actually used for simulation?

Comment: This is the schematic actually used for simulation

Comment: Hi Ibrahim – can you please add screenshots of: 1. PWM signal coming out of the Arduino board, 2. Q1 gate to source voltage, 3. switch node voltage (diode cathode to GND) This would be very useful in debugging!

Comment: @milovankosach Hello. I did add them

Comment: What is even more hilarious, after I seperate the PWM pin from the circuit, load voltmeter still shows something around 28 volts :(

Comment: I rolled back your edit because you changed the circuit after the question received an answer, and that edit rendered the answer no longer appropriate to the schematic.

Answer (score 3):

Your circuit does not use voltage feedback from \$V_{out}\$ to control the duty ratio. (Or, at least your schematic does not show any such feedback.) If you circuit were operating in continuous conduction mode (CCM) it would give an output voltage approximately proportional to the duty cycle. However, when there is no load, or the load current is small, the converter operates in discontinuous conduction mode (DCM). In DCM, the output voltage may rise much higher than in CCM, and the output voltage depends not only on the duty ratio, but also on the load current.

You can address this problem either by adding voltage feedback from \$V_{out}\$ to control the duty ratio (was R8 meant to be connected to \$V_{out}\$?), or you could live with the behavior, and rely upon their being a sufficient load current to keep your converter operating in CCM, in which case your voltage will be fixed by the duty ratio.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you will need to protect the gate of your MOSFET from excessive (\$\ge\$ 20 V) \$V_{gs}\$.

Comment: Check out my edit. Now also tried doing that. In this case, Vout starts from 0 and stucks at 1.7Vs